# Portainer persistent logs

Tags: docker, logging, portainer

I'm using `portainer` to manage my docker containers.
As the application starts, I can see the logs, but after a while they just disappear.

How can I configure `portainer` to persist the logs?
I have mounted a volume to the portainer container (`/data`).

Comment: Are you talking about Portainer logs or about the logs of another container?